# How to create an object file with a big binary char[] array on Linux?

Tags: linux, arrays, binary, elf

I need tool which is equivalent to:

```
$ echo 'char bar[] = {65, 66, 67};' >foo.c
$ gcc -c foo.c
```

I have a multi-megabyte binary file to be put to the `bar` array, and I need it without creating an `.c` file: I'd like the `.o` file be created directly from the binary file. Another option can be creating `.s` or `.S` files, but I'd like to avoid that as well. Is there a tool in *binutils* etc. which can do the job?

An update: `gcc` segfaults for a 9 MB binary file. `as` works, but it's slow and the the temporary `.s` file is too large.

Comment: You should report the segfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a long time the easiest solution was creating an `.s` or an `.S` file.

*binutils* doesn't contain anything useful.

There is a 2-step trick which is fast and uses little memory:

Step 1. Create a and compile a .c file which contains the symbol of the right size, but it has a short signature instead of the real, long data. It should look like:

```
const char hi[1234567] = "SIGNATURE";
const char *hi_end = hi + sizeof(hi) / sizeof(char);
```

Step 2. Find the bytes `SIGNATURE` in the .o file generated by the compiler, and replace it (and the following `'\0'`s) with the data from the real binary data file.

The Perl script [cobjgen](http://github.com/pts/cobjgen/blob/master/cobjgen) automates both steps. See this [blog post](http://ptspts.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-add-very-large-data-blobs-to-c.html) for a more detailed analysis and usage instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use objcopy --add-section to create a section with contents found in a file.  I think you'll need to use a linker script to add a symbol pointing at the start of the new section.

Comment: Sorry, no. objcopy should be trivial to get right using just the manual. Linker scripts are somewhat harder.